# How to Add HTML5 Video controls dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have a video slider which does not include controls in the 'video' tags.  I am using a custom play button to initiate videos.  However, once the video has begun playing, I am fading out my custom play button and would like the standard html5 video controls to take over.  Is there a way to append the controls to html5 video only if the video is playing.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try and read some tutorials and show you what you got? I'm pretty sure there are lots of tutorials just search up on google

Comment: All the tutorials I find are on creating custom HTML5 video controls.  That's fine and most have been helpful but I haven't been able to find anything to show me how to initiate default controls

Comment: Never mind, I found it.  Thanks for making me dig deeper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
    $('#btn').on('click',
                 function(){
                     $('#vid')[0].play();
                     $(this).hide();});
  
    $('#vid').on('play', function (e) {
   
        $(this).attr('controls','true');
});
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="400" id="vid" >
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
 
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
    
    <button id="btn">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to utilize the ['playing' listener event](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).

```
$('video').on('playing', function (e) {
  if (!this.hasAttribute("controls")) {
     this.setAttribute("controls","controls") 
  }
});
```

When the `playing` listener fires, you can check and see if the controls have been added. If they don't exist, it will see the native `controls` attribute.